# Parsing a binary file to look for URIs in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, uri, binaryfiles

My goal is to look for URIs in a binary file using C++. I have already written the code which tells me whether a given string is a correct URI or not (so my code would return TRUE for "http://a.pl" and FALSE for "xdG:" for example). However, I have a hard time trying to make it work for whole files. I cannot just check the whole file word-by-word, because URIs can be hidden somewhere inside words, e.g.

...href="http://a.pl">link...

The obvious sollution I have come up with is to check words character-by-character, so first whether ...href="http://a.pl">link... is a URI, then ...ref="http://a.pl">link..., then ...ef="http://a.pl">link... and so on. But that seems like a very slow sollution. How can I make it more efficient?

Comment: If your "binary" file is HTML, use a parser to find all href´s of a-tags etc. instead of your method

Comment: I'm not so sure what you're asking about, but [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) might come in handy ...

Comment: @deviantfan Files can have random content, so I'm afraid it's no use in this case :)

Comment: Is the file binary or text?  What is the format of the file?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (if you want to avoid using a real parser) would be to search for `://` first, which should be quite simple and efficient and which has to be a part of any URI you are interested in (in theory, there may be others, if you need them too, just search for the `:`). Then search backwards for the scheme (`http` or `ftp` or whatever) by checking for `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `+`, `-` and `.`. Then run your algorithm (which hopefully knows where to end?).

If you only need `http`-URIs, you could of course optimize the above to simply look for `http://` and only then call your algorithm.